# string uppercasing adds junk to the end of char array

Tags: c++, string

I am learning c++, I write some code to convert a string to uppercase and display it. I assign a string str with "asdf" and then create a char array pointer and allocate a length same as that of the string.

But after I assign indices of char array with uppercase chars when I try to display char array there are many junk characters appended to  the end. Why does this happen as I have only allocated the char array with a size = "length of string" then how does char array have junk chars at the end even after the actual allocated size.

```
string str{ "asdf" };
char* str_c = new char[str.length()];   
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    str_c[i] = toupper(str[i]);     
}
cout << str_c; // displays ASDF²▌r┐│w²A∙
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your char array needs to be one character longer than the length of the string, for the null terminator

```
string str{ "asdf" };
char* str_c = new char[str.length() + 1];   
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    str_c[i] = toupper(str[i]);     
}
str_c[str.length()] = '\0';
cout << str_c; // displays ASDF
```

In C-style strings (char*) the length of the string is not stored in memory. Thus, it must use some other way to determine where the string ends. The way it does that is by assuming that the string is all the bytes until the byte that is equal to zero (so-called null-terminator).

Without explicitly allocating an extra byte for the null terminator, and setting it, your string continues with the garbage that happens to be after the bytes you have allocated until it encounters (accidentally) the nearest 0.

Comment: thanks this works . but could you please explain me why "str_c[str.length()] = 0;" is required?

Comment: In C-style strings (`char*`) the length of the string is not stored in memory. Thus, it must use some other way to determine where the string ends. The way it does that is by assuming that the string is all the bytes until the byte that is equal to zero (so-called null-terminator).

Comment: oh that is interesting does it mean I cant have 0 as a char in between my string.

Comment: Most of the libraries (e.g. `cout` that you use from `iostream`, or most of the stuff from `string.h`) will break if you need to have 0 bytes in your `char*`s. `string` class (`str` in your code was an instance of `string`) does store the length, and in many cases handles 0 bytes inside correctly. This article has a good comparison https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/07/26/stdstring-vs-c-strings/

Comment: Interesting side note: `toupper`'s parameter is an `int`, not a `char`, to allow for out of band codes like EOF. This can lead to interesting problems when you have a signed `char`s. The standard recommendation is to cast the `char` to an `unsigned char` before calling, just to be on the safe side.